# How do i make the ejs variable work that i send from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, variables, ejs, src

I am tring to get a variable that i send from nodejs to ejs to work. But for some reason it wont, i cant figure out why.

This is the index.js:

```js
var newOne = "Yes"

router.get('/main', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>
  res.render('main',  {
    user: req.user,
    newOneInView : newOne
  })
)
```

And this is in the main.ejs file:

```html
<%if (newOneInView == "Yes") { %>
  document.getElementById("avatar").src = "/static/images/Apocaliptic1.png";
  <% } %>
```

So what i am trying to achieve is that variable will be seen from the nodejs at the main.ejs page but some reason it wont change the image SRC. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template you need to make sure that you place the code for changing the `src` attribute in a script that is placed after the element (alternatively you can use a listener for the content to be loaded), e.g:

```
<body>
<img id="avatar" src="/some-other-path"/>
<script>
    <% if (newOneInView === "Yes") { %>
    document.getElementById("avatar").src = "/static/images/Apocaliptic1.png";
    <% } %>
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks the red errors in the ejs file kinda threw me off, but it seems to work now. Thanks :)

Comment: One more thing @eol, if i want to change the variable by pressing a button how would i write that?

Comment: This is a very broad question - you mean you want to change the `src` by clicking on a button?  I suggest you post a new question with all the details, so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: Hmm no not the src, i mean the variable it self, so the newOneInView. So if i would press a button it would change to "No" for example.

Comment: Do you know how i could do that? @eol

Comment: You will have to provide an endpoint on your server to change the variable through e.g. a http-request as it obviously lives on the server. But as I said, it's probably easier if you post a separate question regarding this.